# Why does an empty minipage not respect the specified width?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I just realized that an empty minipage does not work as a placeholder since it neglects the specified width. Adding, for example, a `\strut` achieves the desired result. Maybe someone can enlighten me why some phantom element is needed here and whether or not a `\strut` is what you should use in this case.

*Disclaimer: I am not actually looking for an alternative to using minipage. I am just curious about the reasons why it doesn't work as I expected it to work.*

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]

  \vspace{1em}%

  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    % Placing a \strut here, the width would be respected
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1]%
  \end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just as an observation `\leavevmode` also works as material to get the box to "be there"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width argument is used to set `\hsize` locally, that is the width used for linebreaking. So if you have any horizontal materal in the content, it will cause a paragraph and at least one line wiill be `\hsize` wide (or over-full).

If there is no content (or more specifically no horizontal mode) then the box will be the width of its content, which will be 0pt, for an empty box